# jpg to pdf without data loss

Tags: pdf, conversion, jpeg

Trying to make such things:

1st step:

```
convert img.jpg img.pdf
```

2nd step:

```
pdfimages -j img.pdf img1
```

Comparing source and extracted images in HEX shows difference. How to make such conversion without data loss?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to use `pdflatex` instead of `convert`.

You need in a extra file, which is here called `image.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PreviewMacro[{*[][]{}}]{\includegraphics}
\begin{document}
   \includegraphics{img.jpg}
\end{document}
```

Then run `pdflatex image.tex` to generate image.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that there's an entire JPEG - metadata *and* picture data, in JFIF/JPEG format within the PDF?  If not, then even if the image data is extracted verbatim, `pdfimages` will have to reconstruct the container and that may not match.

You can get a similar situation with audio files and tags etc. - you can't do sum comparisons if you change the metadata.

IN that situation, you need to calculate hashes for just the data portion, rather than  the whole file.

Comment: The approach with `convert` does really return a different picture. Comparing the images with `gimp` shows slight differences. With `pdflatex` as described in my answer, you get exactly the same image back - including the original metadata.