# Stitch two JPEGs together into a PDF

Tags: pdf, jpeg

I need to take two 8.5in by 11in JPEG images and merge them together into two pages of a PDF. Is there a commandline or GUI tool for this?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168165/ways-to-convert-and-combine-image-files-into-a-pdf-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you're interested in a two-pages pdf, you can do something similar

```
convert input1.jpg output1.pdf
convert input2.jpg output2.pdf
```

The next step is to make one pdf out of it. This can be easily done with `gs`. As explained here: https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8229-putting-together-pdf-files

You can also use the imagemagick toolkit to first stitch the jpg images, which can be done from command-line only.

```
convert -append input1.jpg input2.jpg output.jpg
convert output.jpg output.pdf
```

More info http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append

Comment: what is the difference of your solution from `convert intput1.jpg input2.jpg output.pdf`?

Answer (score 5):

One way is to create a LaTeX document which includes the images and in turn creates one `pdf` document holding both `jpg`s. Ruthlessly taken from [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34144/13742): you could do something like the following. Create a file `image.tex` with the content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PreviewMacro[{*[][]{}}]{\includegraphics}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{img1.jpg}
\newpage
\includegraphics{img2.jpg}
\end{document}
```

Then compile the file into a `pdf` document:

```
$ pdflatex image.tex
```

Comment: If the OP has to do this more often, it might be worth having a closer look at the [`pdfjam` tools](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) – they don't do what you'd like to achieve, but it's an example of how to create LaTeX-files on-the-fly to automate this answer into a tiny script.

Answer (score 2):

First create two pdfs for the two jpeg images using the OpenOffice word processor. Then you can merge the two pdfs using [PDF-Shuffler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/).

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment on the state of the art rather than an answer, but:

I believe using a text editor (like LibreOffice or OpenOffice.org) or a text processor (like LaTeX) to generate a pdf version of the jpeg images is a bit overkill, as it is something as simple as a single image.

OTOH `convert` actually converts, it does not simply put the JPEG image inside a PDF container (maybe I'm wrong here and PDF does not support JPEG streams, but I think it does), so although `convert` is way easier and quicker, it's still a bit `overkill` — ironically, maybe either LibreOffice or LaTeX actually just copy the JPEG instead of converting it (but here I'd say it's not worth the trouble).

For the joining step, you can either use, as already pointed out, `gs`. There is also `pdftk`, which, IIRC, just glues the PDFs together (gs will read the PDFs and render a new pdf out of it (at least when used with `pdfwrite`, you're free to generate, e.g., a postscript file instead, although that's of little use here).

Comment: Here the syntax for pdftk: `pdftk img1.pdf img2.pdf output all.pdf`

Comment: And if you can't use `pdftk` (e.g. on fedora 21), `qpdf --empty --pages 1.pdf 2.pdf -- all.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283245/using-ghostscript-to-convert-jpeg-to-pdf.

But it seems that the original JPEG's might be altered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new folder, add them to this folder and make sure they have a `.jpg` file ending (case might matter)
2. Go to that folder and type in terminal `convert *.jpg output.pdf`

This works with as many JPGs as you want. You will get one n-pages PDF-file for n JPG-files.